# Configure Juniper SRX550 for CACTI Monitoring

Tags: cacti

I'm back with a new task.  I need to monitor a Juniper SRX550 via CACTI (version 0.8.8c).  I used a template supplied in one forums and it is partially working.  I can monitor the CPU, Memory, temperature and storage of the device.  What I need to monitor are the interfaces. I run the Assiociated data query from Cacti and got this result.  Is this an OID issue?  Can somebody point me to the proper OID list for this device or better if someone can show me a template to use for this device.

- Running data query [13].
- Found type = '3' [SNMP Query].
- Found data query XML file at '/var/www/html/cacti-0.8.8c/resource/snmp_queries/interface.xml'
- XML file parsed ok.
- Executing SNMP get for num of indexes @ '.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.1.0' Index Count: 167
- Executing SNMP walk for list of indexes @ '.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1' Index Count: 167
- Index found at OID: '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.1' value: '1'
- Index found at OID: '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.2' value: '2'
- Index found at OID: '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.3' value: '3'
- Index found at OID: '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.4' value: '4'
- Index found at OID: '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.6' value: '6'
- Index found at OID: '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.7' value: '7'
- Index found at OID: '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.8' value: '8'
- Index found at OID: '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.9' value: '9'
  .
  .
  .
- Executing SNMP walk for data @ '.1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.2'
- Found item [ifIP='10.0.0.1'] index: 22 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='10.0.0.16'] index: 22 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='10.10.10.1'] index: 13 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='10.10.200.45'] index: 634 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='10.20.100.5'] index: 618 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='10.62.65.2'] index: 632 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='10.100.102.254'] index: 644 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='10.100.104.254'] index: 658 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='10.100.200.6'] index: 640 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='10.100.200.14'] index: 648 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='30.17.0.200'] index: 550 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='30.18.0.200'] index: 553 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='118.201.184.242'] index: 601 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='127.0.0.1'] index: 21 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='128.0.0.1'] index: 22 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='128.0.0.4'] index: 22 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='128.0.1.16'] index: 22 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='129.16.0.1'] index: 14 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='172.17.129.1'] index: 624 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='172.17.129.5'] index: 627 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='192.168.4.254'] index: 617 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='192.168.5.2'] index: 619 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='192.168.6.254'] index: 630 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='192.168.12.254'] index: 659 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='192.168.201.254'] index: 602 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='192.168.210.254'] index: 603 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='192.168.247.1'] index: 621 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='192.168.252.1'] index: 620 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='192.168.255.65'] index: 622 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='203.116.8.2'] index: 600 [from regexp oid parse]
- Found item [ifIP='203.116.17.30'] index: 616 [from regexp oid parse]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that you can use snmpwalk via the command line.
2. Try using the cacti default Traffic Templates to graph traffic. if thi works.
3. Link this template to your juniper host.
4. If it does not work, you will have to create a data and graph template based on the cacti default template.

Comment: Thanks Templum for the steps.  Unfortunately, when I use the cacti default template, not all interface of the SRX550 generates a graph.  I'll monitor this at the moment and hope to find additional solutions.

Comment: Check that the interfaces responds to traffic oids using your command line.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  Template was incomplete.  I added new data and graph templates for the additional interface.  Looks ok now.  Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the partial output you posted is correct. 
The standard interface.xml file that comes with Cacti works great.  I suggest you check the following.
Look in the "Associated Data Queries" section for your device.  You should see "SNMP - Interface Statistics" and in the "Status" column you should see the number of Items and Rows discovered for the SRX550, in your example I believe there would be 167 rows.

Next when you go "Create Graphs for this host" you should see a section "Data Query [SNMP - Interface Statistics]" where you select the interfaces you want to create graphs for.    Be sure to select the "graph type" in the lower right as well and hit the "create" button.

Comment: thanks.  Created additional Data and Graph Templates.  Everything is ok now.